# multiple instances of same marker in iOS augmented reality

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, vuforia, qcar-sdk

I have some augmented reality issue here..I have to detect multiple instances of same images..I used vuforia, but it seems to me that it doesn't have support for that..string have that support but it costs $999 which is too expensive for me..is there any free option to do that?

Comment: I don't get the context. What do you mean by "multiple instances of same images"? Vuforia allows detecting one or multiple images, even more images in the same scene (more markers in the same time, e.g. FrameMarkers  in the Vuforia's sample list).

Comment: suppose one images appears in three positions in the frame..I am not able to detect all the three..vuforia is detecting only one..

Comment: got it. Indeed, I don't think they provide this functionality..

Comment: [This discussion](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/can-i-detect-multiple-identical-targets) on the Vuforia forum tends to prove that it's not possible too...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to detect multiple instances of the same image target within the camera frame at one time. Although, you can detect multiple different image target simultaneously within the range of camera at one time using

```
QCAR::setHint(QCAR::HINT_MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_IMAGE_TARGETS, 2);
```